# child pid xxxx exit signal Segmentation fault

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am running a drupal site. It was working fine. Later I installed and enabled some Panopoly News and Panopoly Demo modules, after which my site stops working and throwing the following error on browser.

> The connection to the server was reset while the page was loading. The
>   site could be temporarily unavailable or too busy. Try again in a few
>   moments. If you are unable to load any pages, check your computer's
>   network connection. If your computer or network is protected by a
>   firewall or proxy, make sure that Firefox is permitted to access the
>   Web.

When I check apache error log I am getting these errors:

```
[Sat Jan 26 00:04:51 2013] [notice] child pid 2393 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
[Sat Jan 26 00:04:53 2013] [notice] child pid 2391 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

Can these modules cause this problem, or is this a server (ie, non-Drupal) problem?

Comment: What happens when you disable/remove the plugins ?